# Python program using dbm database on Mac crashes when database is over 1 Gig

Tags: python

I'm having this same problem with both python2 and python3 on my Mac running Yosemite 10.10.2 (I have 8GiB of RAM)

I had written some code that adds entries to two different dictionaries and searches for entries in both dictionaries. However, the dictionaries are now getting too big to store in RAM and so I am trying to use the simple "dbm" module (import dbm) database provided with python/python3...

But the db code crashes when the combined size of both dictionaries exceeds a Gig! This is an even worse size limitation than storing the dictionaries in RAM since there I can go up to (and have gone up to) about 8Gigs... I'm wondering if anyone has run into python crashing with large dbm databases on mac?

Here's some code that may explain better than my English explanation:

```
myDB=dbm.open('mine','c')
targDB=dbm.open('cats','c')
count=0
countTarg=0
while(True):
    headerTarg=str(countTarg).encode("utf-8")
    testString=f(headerTarg)  #function f returns byte string
    if testString in myDB:
        myHeader=myDB[testString]
        targHeader=headerTarg
        break
    else:
        targDB[testString]=str(countTarg).encode("utf-8")
        countTarg+=1

    header=str(count).encode("utf-8")
    checkMeString=g(header) #function g returns byte string
    if checkMeString in targDB:
        targHeader=targDB[checkMeString]
        myHeader=header
        break
    else:
        myDB[checkMeString]=str(count).encode("utf-8")
        count+=1
```

Actually, I don't think the details of the code matter much. Basically, these databases get created and get more and more entries, and are searched in the loop until a match is found. However, sometimes it takes a very long time to find a match and very large databases are required... and if the combined database size is bigger than a Gig the code crashes.

If I use dictionaries in RAM instead of database files the code doesn't crash, but in that case I am limited by the size of RAM. So, I want to switch to some kind of database. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Finally, I was wondering, should I just eschew the built in dbm module altogether and go with some SQL module? If that's the way to go, please let me know. Thank you.

EDIT: Here is the crash report as requested:

```
Process:               Python [553]
Path:                  /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python
Identifier:            Python
Version:               3.4.2 (3.4.2)
Code Type:             X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:        bash [308]
Responsible:           Terminal [305]
User ID:               501

Date/Time:             2015-02-03 19:16:21.916 -0800
OS Version:            Mac OS X 10.10.2 (14C109)
Report Version:        11
Anonymous UUID:        05C92373-2318-7473-A6A2-125AD71157CF


Time Awake Since Boot: 3300 seconds

Crashed Thread:        0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Exception Type:        EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Codes:       KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x0000000000000008

VM Regions Near 0x8:
--> 
    __TEXT                 0000000100000000-0000000100001000 [    4K] r-x/rwx SM=COW  /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python

Thread 0 Crashed:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff92538460 __get_buf + 137
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff925370e0 hash_access + 104
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff92539fc3 dbm_fetch + 29
3   _dbm.so                         0x00000001003f672c dbm_contains + 76
4   org.python.python               0x00000001000e291d PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 21869
5   org.python.python               0x00000001000e604d PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 2349
6   org.python.python               0x00000001000e610f PyEval_EvalCode + 63
7   org.python.python               0x000000010011064e PyRun_FileExFlags + 206
8   org.python.python               0x00000001001109fd PyRun_SimpleFileExFlags + 717
9   org.python.python               0x00000001001281be Py_Main + 3262
10  org.python.python               0x0000000100000e32 0x100000000 + 3634
11  org.python.python               0x0000000100000c84 0x100000000 + 3204

Thread 0 crashed with X86 Thread State (64-bit):
  rax: 0x0000000000000000  rbx: 0x0000000000000000  rcx: 0x0000000000000000  rdx: 0x0000000000000000
  rdi: 0x0000000000000101  rsi: 0x0000000000010100  rbp: 0x00007fff5bfff210  rsp: 0x00007fff5bfff1b0
   r8: 0x0000000100913800   r9: 0x00007fff5bfff2f0  r10: 0x0000000000000000  r11: 0x00000001003f66e0
  r12: 0x0000000100434620  r13: 0x0000000100434620  r14: 0x00000001003d5438  r15: 0x000000010099c000
  rip: 0x00007fff92538460  rfl: 0x0000000000010206  cr2: 0x0000000000000008

Logical CPU:     2
Error Code:      0x00000006
Trap Number:     14


Binary Images:
       0x100000000 -        0x100000ff7 +org.python.python (3.4.2 - 3.4.2) <D486A30F-8362-E06E-B0A9-6E3CF809F506> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python
       0x100003000 -        0x1001f1fe7 +org.python.python (3.4.2, [c] 2004-2014 Python Software Foundation. - 3.4.2) <E1D17D5C-238B-E208-B930-CBF0CE505400> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/Python
       0x1003f5000 -        0x1003f6ff7 +_dbm.so (???) <875B3ED4-96DE-7FFA-F760-79CA470CCE40> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/lib-dynload/_dbm.so
       0x1003fa000 -        0x1003fcff7 +_hashlib.so (???) <6F568F50-759E-6851-2A21-DCCBFDD4AADA> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/lib-dynload/_hashlib.so
       0x1020b1000 -        0x1020b6ff7 +_struct.so (???) <F0078D5D-9663-F767-63F7-FDE4C6DDE1B2> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/lib-dynload/_struct.so
       0x1020be000 -        0x1020f4ff7  libssl.0.9.8.dylib (52.10.1) <4A2D6ECA-A07E-38B5-98D4-315A4A1E8CE6> /usr/lib/libssl.0.9.8.dylib
       0x10210a000 -        0x10210bff7 +_heapq.so (???) <199DA290-627E-D49D-2525-4D3CE9D2C8A2> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/lib-dynload/_heapq.so
    0x7fff69e52000 -     0x7fff69e88837  dyld (353.2.1) <65DCCB06-339C-3E25-9702-600A28291D0E> /usr/lib/dyld
    0x7fff8a1c9000 -     0x7fff8a2adfff  libcrypto.0.9.8.dylib (52.10.1) <2A2924DE-63FB-37F6-B102-84D69240675B> /usr/lib/libcrypto.0.9.8.dylib
    0x7fff8b00d000 -     0x7fff8b038fff  libc++abi.dylib (125) <88A22A0F-87C6-3002-BFBA-AC0F2808B8B9> /usr/lib/libc++abi.dylib
    0x7fff8b0e7000 -     0x7fff8b0fdff7  libsystem_asl.dylib (267) <F153AC5B-0542-356E-88C8-20A62CA704E2> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_asl.dylib
    0x7fff8d6a5000 -     0x7fff8d6d5fff  libsystem_m.dylib (3086.1) <1E12AB45-6D96-36D0-A226-F24D9FB0D9D6> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_m.dylib
    0x7fff8dd19000 -     0x7fff8dd2aff7  libz.1.dylib (55) <88C7C7DE-04B8-316F-8B74-ACD9F3DE1AA1> /usr/lib/libz.1.dylib
    0x7fff8dd50000 -     0x7fff8dd59ff7  libsystem_notify.dylib (133.1.1) <61147800-F320-3DAA-850C-BADF33855F29> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_notify.dylib
    0x7fff8e418000 -     0x7fff8e435fff  libsystem_kernel.dylib (2782.10.72) <97CD7ACD-EA0C-3434-BEFC-FCD013D6BB73> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_kernel.dylib
    0x7fff8e465000 -     0x7fff8e48fff7  libdispatch.dylib (442.1.4) <502CF32B-669B-3709-8862-08188225E4F0> /usr/lib/system/libdispatch.dylib
    0x7fff8e492000 -     0x7fff8e493fff  libDiagnosticMessagesClient.dylib (100) <2EE8E436-5CDC-34C5-9959-5BA218D507FB> /usr/lib/libDiagnosticMessagesClient.dylib
    0x7fff8e5a1000 -     0x7fff8e5a3fff  libsystem_configuration.dylib (699.1.5) <5E14864E-089A-3D84-85A4-980B776427A8> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_configuration.dylib
    0x7fff8e5a4000 -     0x7fff8e5a5ff7  libsystem_blocks.dylib (65) <9615D10A-FCA7-3BE4-AA1A-1B195DACE1A1> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_blocks.dylib
    0x7fff8e61a000 -     0x7fff8e622fff  libsystem_platform.dylib (63) <64E34079-D712-3D66-9CE2-418624A5C040> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_platform.dylib
    0x7fff8ea00000 -     0x7fff8ea28fff  libsystem_info.dylib (459) <B85A85D5-8530-3A93-B0C3-4DEC41F79478> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_info.dylib
    0x7fff8eb04000 -     0x7fff8eb06ff7  libquarantine.dylib (76) <DC041627-2D92-361C-BABF-A869A5C72293> /usr/lib/system/libquarantine.dylib
    0x7fff8f05a000 -     0x7fff8f0aefff  libc++.1.dylib (120) <1B9530FD-989B-3174-BB1C-BDC159501710> /usr/lib/libc++.1.dylib
    0x7fff8f119000 -     0x7fff8f11afff  libSystem.B.dylib (1213) <90B107BC-FF74-32CC-B1CF-4E02F544D957> /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
    0x7fff8f3fa000 -     0x7fff8f3fbfff  com.apple.TrustEvaluationAgent (2.0 - 25) <2D61A2C3-C83E-3A3F-8EC1-736DBEC250AB> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/TrustEvaluationAgent.framework/Versions/A/TrustEvaluationAgent
    0x7fff8f5b7000 -     0x7fff8f5c2fff  libcommonCrypto.dylib (60061) <D381EBC6-69D8-31D3-8084-5A80A32CB748> /usr/lib/system/libcommonCrypto.dylib
    0x7fff900d8000 -     0x7fff900ddff7  libsystem_stats.dylib (163.10.18) <9B8CCF24-DDDB-399A-9237-4BEC225D2E8C> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_stats.dylib
    0x7fff900de000 -     0x7fff900efff7  libsystem_coretls.dylib (35.1.2) <BC691CD1-17B6-39A5-BD02-AF973695FD1D> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_coretls.dylib
    0x7fff900f0000 -     0x7fff90166fe7  libcorecrypto.dylib (233.1.2) <E1789801-3985-3949-B736-6B3378873301> /usr/lib/system/libcorecrypto.dylib
    0x7fff90177000 -     0x7fff9017cff7  libunwind.dylib (35.3) <BE7E51A0-B6EA-3A54-9CCA-9D88F683A6D6> /usr/lib/system/libunwind.dylib
    0x7fff902a9000 -     0x7fff902b0ff7  libcompiler_rt.dylib (35) <BF8FC133-EE10-3DA6-9B90-92039E28678F> /usr/lib/system/libcompiler_rt.dylib
    0x7fff91a77000 -     0x7fff91a80fff  libsystem_pthread.dylib (105.10.1) <3103AA7F-3BAE-3673-9649-47FFD7E15C97> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_pthread.dylib
    0x7fff91a81000 -     0x7fff91ac7ff7  libauto.dylib (186) <A260789B-D4D8-316A-9490-254767B8A5F1> /usr/lib/libauto.dylib
    0x7fff9204d000 -     0x7fff9224746f  libobjc.A.dylib (647) <759E155D-BC42-3D4E-869B-6F57D477177C> /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib
    0x7fff92248000 -     0x7fff92248ff7  libkeymgr.dylib (28) <77845842-DE70-3CC5-BD01-C3D14227CED5> /usr/lib/system/libkeymgr.dylib
    0x7fff9242a000 -     0x7fff92462ffb  libsystem_network.dylib (411.1) <2EC3A005-473F-3C36-A665-F88B5BACC7F0> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_network.dylib
    0x7fff9251f000 -     0x7fff925abff7  libsystem_c.dylib (1044.10.1) <199ED5EB-77A1-3D43-AA51-81779CE0A742> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib
    0x7fff929cd000 -     0x7fff929d3ff7  libsystem_networkextension.dylib (167.1.10) <29AB225B-D7FB-30ED-9600-65D44B9A9442> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_networkextension.dylib
    0x7fff929d6000 -     0x7fff929d7ffb  libremovefile.dylib (35) <3485B5F4-6CE8-3C62-8DFD-8736ED6E8531> /usr/lib/system/libremovefile.dylib
    0x7fff92b0e000 -     0x7fff92b0eff7  liblaunch.dylib (559.10.3) <DFCDEBDF-8247-3DC7-9879-E7E497DDA4B4> /usr/lib/system/liblaunch.dylib
    0x7fff92de7000 -     0x7fff92fccff3  libicucore.A.dylib (531.31) <B08E00D5-13C6-3391-AB3A-8DE693D3B42E> /usr/lib/libicucore.A.dylib
    0x7fff92fcd000 -     0x7fff93363fff  com.apple.CoreFoundation (6.9 - 1152) <CBD1591C-405E-376E-87E9-B264610EBF49> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Versions/A/CoreFoundation
    0x7fff9355d000 -     0x7fff9355efff  libsystem_secinit.dylib (18) <581DAD0F-6B63-3A48-B63B-917AF799ABAA> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_secinit.dylib
    0x7fff9404e000 -     0x7fff94054fff  libsystem_trace.dylib (72.1.3) <A9E6B7D8-C327-3742-AC54-86C94218B1DF> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_trace.dylib
    0x7fff94055000 -     0x7fff94057ff7  libsystem_sandbox.dylib (358.1.1) <95312E09-DA28-324A-A084-F3E574D0210E> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_sandbox.dylib
    0x7fff95556000 -     0x7fff95556ff7  libunc.dylib (29) <5676F7EA-C1DF-329F-B006-D2C3022B7D70> /usr/lib/system/libunc.dylib
    0x7fff96115000 -     0x7fff96117ff7  libsystem_coreservices.dylib (9) <41B7C578-5A53-31C8-A96F-C73E030B0938> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_coreservices.dylib
    0x7fff96404000 -     0x7fff96407ff7  libdyld.dylib (353.2.1) <4E33E416-F1D8-3598-B8CC-6863E2ECD0E6> /usr/lib/system/libdyld.dylib
    0x7fff96e6f000 -     0x7fff96e77ffb  libcopyfile.dylib (118.1.2) <0C68D3A6-ACDD-3EF3-991A-CC82C32AB836> /usr/lib/system/libcopyfile.dylib
    0x7fff96e78000 -     0x7fff96e80fff  libsystem_dnssd.dylib (561.1.1) <62B70ECA-E40D-3C63-896E-7F00EC386DDB> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_dnssd.dylib
    0x7fff980c0000 -     0x7fff980c5ff7  libmacho.dylib (862) <126CA2ED-DE91-308F-8881-B9DAEC3C63B6> /usr/lib/system/libmacho.dylib
    0x7fff991c8000 -     0x7fff991ccfff  libcache.dylib (69) <45E9A2E7-99C4-36B2-BEE3-0C4E11614AD1> /usr/lib/system/libcache.dylib
    0x7fff991f0000 -     0x7fff9920cff7  libsystem_malloc.dylib (53.1.1) <19BCC257-5717-3502-A71F-95D65AFA861B> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_malloc.dylib
    0x7fff998ac000 -     0x7fff998d4fff  libxpc.dylib (559.10.3) <876216DC-D5D3-381E-8AF9-49AE464E5107> /usr/lib/system/libxpc.dylib

External Modification Summary:
  Calls made by other processes targeting this process:
    task_for_pid: 21
    thread_create: 0
    thread_set_state: 0
  Calls made by this process:
    task_for_pid: 0
    thread_create: 0
    thread_set_state: 0
  Calls made by all processes on this machine:
    task_for_pid: 89098
    thread_create: 0
    thread_set_state: 0

VM Region Summary:
ReadOnly portion of Libraries: Total=85.5M resident=30.2M(35%) swapped_out_or_unallocated=55.3M(65%)
Writable regions: Total=55.2M written=5552K(10%) resident=6248K(11%) swapped_out=0K(0%) unallocated=49.1M(89%)

REGION TYPE                      VIRTUAL
===========                      =======
Kernel Alloc Once                     4K
MALLOC                             38.4M
MALLOC (admin)                       16K
MALLOC_LARGE (reserved)             512K        reserved VM address space (unallocated)
VM_ALLOCATE                           8K
__DATA                             1764K
__LINKEDIT                         71.1M
__TEXT                             14.5M
__UNICODE                           544K
__UNIXSTACK                        16.0M
shared memory                         4K
===========                      =======
TOTAL                             142.7M
TOTAL, minus reserved VM space    142.2M


Model: MacBookAir6,2, BootROM MBA61.0099.B18, 2 processors, Intel Core i7, 1.7 GHz, 8 GB, SMC 2.13f15
Graphics: Intel HD Graphics 5000, Intel HD Graphics 5000, Built-In
Memory Module: BANK 0/DIMM0, 4 GB, DDR3, 1600 MHz, 0x80CE, 0x4B3445364533303445452D45474345000000
Memory Module: BANK 1/DIMM0, 4 GB, DDR3, 1600 MHz, 0x80CE, 0x4B3445364533303445452D45474345000000
AirPort: spairport_wireless_card_type_airport_extreme (0x14E4, 0x117), Broadcom BCM43xx 1.0 (7.15.159.13.12)
Bluetooth: Version 4.3.2f6 15235, 3 services, 27 devices, 1 incoming serial ports
Network Service: Wi-Fi, AirPort, en0
Serial ATA Device: APPLE SSD SM0512F, 500.28 GB
USB Device: Internal Memory Card Reader
USB Device: BRCM20702 Hub
USB Device: Bluetooth USB Host Controller
Thunderbolt Bus: MacBook Air, Apple Inc., 23.6
```

Comment: Yeah, I get a very lengthy crash report from Yosemite

Comment: would you mind to edit your question & paste it there?

Comment: Yes, I will. Just give me one second to see if I need to redact anything...

Comment: Yes, a SQL module is the way to go if you have gigs of data.

Comment: Is there any chance that the filesystem on which the dbm files are being written is becoming full, i.e. it's free space before running your code is about 1GiB? I have replicated that scenario (admittedly in Linux) and found that the dbm library/Python don't handle it gracefully. On my system Python crashes with SIGBUS (Bus error) which is not all that dissimilar to the SIGSEGV (segmentation fault) that you are seeing.

Comment: No, there is plenty of space on the file system. ~400GB.

Comment: Is there any filesystem file size limit of 1GiB, or some other quota(1) limit? Can you create a > 1GiB file e.g. using `dd if=/dev/zero of=bigfile -bs $((1024*1024*512)) count=3` to create a 1.5 GiB file.

Comment: No such issue... 3+0 records in; 3+0 records out; 1610612736 bytes transferred in 2.508184 secs. "ls -l" shows a 1.5GiB file...